# Integrate Azure Devops React UI component in Aurelia

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-devops, aurelia, azure-devops-extensions

I have created an Azure DevOps extension with typescript/Aurelia.
Now I want to integrate React Components into this extension to use the default Styling from Azure DevOps.

When I was using just react I could simply use the following code to display a card with inner HTML.

```
<Card className="flex-grow">
    <b>Hello World<b/>
</Card>
```

But because I use Aurelia I have to make a component to wrap the react component. Unfortunately there is a bug in my code, so that the inner HTML is not rendered.

```
@noView()
@autoinject()
@customElement('basic-card')
export class ReactElement {

    reactComponent: any = {};
    element: Element;

    constructor(element: Element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    render() {
        this.reactComponent = ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(Card, null, this.element.children),
            this.element
        );
    }

    bind() {
        this.render();
    }

    dataChanged(newVal) {
        this.bind();
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<basic-card>
  <b>Hello World</b>
</basic-card>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this piece of code so i see the HTML **Hello world** in my card?